# Hibernate ClassCastException ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, wildfly

We want to use another Hibernate version (5.2.18.Final, JPA 2.1) on our application server (Wildfly V16.0)
but we are getting following exception :

```
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"david-app.ear#examplePersistenceUnit\".__FIRST_PHASE__" => "java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategy (org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl is in unnamed module of loader 'org.hibernate:5.2.18.Final@5.2.18.Final' @155c18e0; org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategy is in unnamed module of loader 'org.hibernate@5.3.9.Final' @102121eb)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategy (org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl is in unnamed module of loader 'org.hibernate:5.2.18.Final@5.2.18.Final' @155c18e0; org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategy is in unnamed module of loader 'org.hibernate@5.3.9.Final' @102121eb)"}}
```

It seems that it's trying to load 2 hibernate versions at the same time but this should be avoided with following configurations:

jboss-deployment-structure.xml (resources/META-INF) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.hibernate" slot="main"/>
    </exclusions>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.hibernate" slot="5.2.18.Final"/>
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">
         <persistence-unit name="examplePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/CoreXADataSource</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:5.2.18.Final"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.wrap_result_sets" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Hibernate module.xml (5.2.18.Final slot) in Wildfly :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module name="org.hibernate:5.2.18.Final" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.8">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="hibernate-core-5.2.18.Final.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="hibernate-entitymanager-5.2.18.Final.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="hibernate-java8-5.2.18.Final.jar"/>
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="com.fasterxml.classmate"/>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.annotation.api"/>
    <module name="javax.enterprise.api"/>
    <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
    <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
    <module name="org.antlr"/>
    <module name="org.dom4j"/>
    <module name="org.javassist" export="true"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.spi"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.jandex"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.vfs"/>
    <module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations"/>
    <module name="org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate5" services="import"/>
    <module name="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache" services="import" optional="true"/>
</dependencies>
```

Anyone has an idea why Wildfly still tries to load his default Hibernate version 5.3.9 while deploying an EAR file ?

Comment: Hey @David, I was facing similar kind of issue for envers related classes. You should use the newer hibernate version provided by jboss/wildfly. It would be easy for you as you are just upgrading it from 5.2.x to 5.3.y. For me, I have to upgrade it from hibernate 4 to hibernate 5

Comment: I fully agree to use the latest hibernate version of Wildfly. But we have some dependencies in place (running Websphere (WAS 9) in production which only supports JPA 2.1 ..

Comment: Then an alternate solution that I can suggest is you that bundle hibernate jars in your deployable instead of using it from modules

Comment: I tried that but it's still loading the Wildfly Hibernate version in parallel.

Comment: It will load wildfly hibernate version in parallel but your code will be referring to jars present in your lib folder

Comment: I bundled hibernate JARs in my EAR/lib folder but I am getting the same exception :)